# Show that there's a unique c such that $f(c)=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

We have a function f: $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, where $|f''(x)| \le 1 $. We also have $|f(c+k)-f(c)-f'(c)k|\le \frac{k^2}{2}$, for $c, c+k \in [-1,1]$.Now, set $c_0=0, k_0=-f(c_0)/f'(c_0)=-1/2$, and $k_n=-f(c_n)/f'(c_n), c_{n+1}=c_n+k_n$.

Then we have a convergent sequence {$c_n$} to approach a limit $c \in [-1,0)$. Show that there is a unique $c \in [-1,0)$ such that $f(c)=0$.

I think if $f$ is strictly increasing or decreasing in the interval [-1,0), and if $f''$ is either positive or negative, and $f$ intersects the x-axis, then we may have a unique zero, but I'm stuck showing these and not sure if I'm on the right track. Please avoid integration. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We have $f'(0)=1$ and $|f''(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x$. By the mean value theorem, this implies $|f'(x)-1|=|f'(x)-f'(0)|=|f''(\xi)(x-0)|\leq |x|<1$ for $x\in(-1,1)$ and hence $f'(x)>0$ on $(-1,1)$ so that $f$ is strictly increasing. This gives you uniqueness.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks, but do you know how to show $f(c)=0$?

Comment: I got the answer, thanks for helping.